# Decompose 3D rotation matrix into rotation around x, y and z-axis

Tags: rotations, matrix-decomposition

I have a rotation matrix **R**, that produces an arbitrary rotation in a 3D space.

I would like to decompose it into 3 rotation matrices **Rx, Ry** and **Rz** so I can use and apply only xy in plane rotation (with **Rz**).

If I determine a rotation to align one of the columns of the rotation matrix **R** to the [0 0 1] vector, it doesn't guarantee that one gets a proper rotation of the entire space, because there are actually infinite solutions!

Thank you!

ANSWER:

http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846 This guy has got a good explanation!

Comment: You can answer this question yourself and mark the answer as the best one in order to make it resolved

Comment: The reference you give uses Euler angles which are of the form $R_x R_z R_x$ not $R_xR_yR_z$...